# How to store or push array of objects

Tags: php

I need to store service_ids and country_ids in an array in this format
array

`[0]["service_id"]` should give service id at 0th

`index`
`array[0]["country_id"]` should give me country id at 0th index and so on.

```
function service_ids($conn) {
$ids = array();
$sql = "SELECT id from services";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
array_push($ids, $row["id"]);
}
return $ids;
}
$service_ids = service_ids($conn);

function country_ids($conn) {
$ids = array();
$sql = "SELECT id FROM countries";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
array_push($ids, $row["id"]);
}
return $ids;
}
$country_ids = country_ids($conn);

`//I am having problem here how to store it.

$z = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($service_ids); $i++) {
$z = array(`
array("service_id"=>$service_ids[$i], "country_id"=>$country_ids[$i])
);
}

 print_r($z);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically overwriting array in each iteration in final loop, instead of that store new array in new array index

```
$z = array();
$counter = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < count($service_ids); $i++) {
    $counter = count($z);
    $z[$counter]["service_id"] = $service_ids[$i];
    $z[$counter]["country_id"] = $country_ids[$i];
}
```